# Weighted Graph DijkstraShortestPath : getpath() does not return path with least cost

Tags: jung

> Thanks for prompt response chessofnerd and Joshua.I am sorry for unclear logsand unclear question.Let me rephrase it.
>
> Joshua:
>     I am storing my weights in DB and retrieving from DB in transformer.
>
> I have 4 devices connected in my topology and  between some devices there are multiple connections and between 2 devices only single connection as shown below.
>
> I am using undirected weighted graph.
>
> Initially all links are assigned weight of 0.When  I request a path between D1 and D4 ,   I increase the weight of each link by 1.
>
> When a second request comes for another path, I  am feeding all the weights through Transformer.
>   When request comes second time, I am correctly feeding weight of 1 for links L1,L2,L3 and 0 for other links.
>
> Since weight of (L4,L5,L3) or (L6,L7,L3) or (L8,L9,L3) is less than weight of (L1,L2,L3), I  am expecting  I will get one of these paths - (L4,L5,L3) or (L6,L7,L3) or (L8,L9,L3). But I  am getting again (L1,L2,L3)
>
> D1---L1-->D2---L2--->D3--L3--->D4
>
> D1---L4-->D2---L5--->D3--L3--->D4
>
> D1---L6-->D2---L7--->D3--L3--->D4
>
> D1---L8-->D2---L9--->D3--L3---->D4
>
> transformer simply returns the weight previosuly stored for link.
>
> Graph topology = new UndirectedSparseMultigraph()
>
> DijkstraShortestPath pathCalculator  = new DijkstraShortestPath(topology, wtTransformer);
>
> List path = pathCalculator.getPath(node1, node2);
>
> private final Transformer wtTransformer = new Transformer() {
>
> ```
>  public Integer transform(Link link) {
>      int weight = getWeightForLink(link, true);
>      return weight;
>   }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: A lot of the log you posted doesn't really mean anything to us. Could you boil it down to the main problem? I also don't see a question?

Comment: It's not clear how you're associating weights with edges, whether you're using caching, or what your topology is.  Providing a minimal example where this happens would be most helpful.

Comment: What does getWeightForLink() do?  Are you sure that the weights it's returning are what you think they are?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating `DijkstraShortestPath` so that it caches results.  Add a "false" parameter to the constructor to change this behavior.

http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/shortestpath/DijkstraShortestPath.html

(And no, the cache does not get poisoned if you change an edge weight; if you do that, it's your responsibility to create a new DSP instance, or not use caching in the first place.)

Comment: Joshua:  Thanks for the response. Even  passing "false"  to  DijkstraShortestPath didn't help my issue. I  am still getting same path previosuly selected even though there are other paths with lower costs. Also for each getpath request I  am constructing a new  DijkstraShortestPath. But it shouldn't be causing this issue though it may cause performance issues though.

Comment: I believe that DijkstraShortestPath's implementation is correct.  Without having code to step through, I can't tell you exactly where your problem is, but I suggest running yours in a debugger to trace the source of the problem.